# Not able to install ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64

Tags: system-installation, kernel

[image]

I have been trying to install Ubuntu on my PC which has a Intel 3rd gen i5 3570K and Asrock b75M motherboard. No dedicated GPU. But whenever I try to boot from a live USB or DVD I always get a error as shown in the screen shot. I cant make any sense of it.

However I am able to install Ubuntu 12 but there are many issues in that. it randomly freezes . Even ctrl+shift+F1 wont work when it freezes. I tried  upgrading the kernel. After that ubuntu 12 also stopped working. Even the latest fedora or Kubuntu is not able to boot. Is there any way how I can resolve this error?

Comment: I was faced same issue, so i changed the SATA cable , used a different SATA power plug from my power supply, After work fine, I think it is small process, so you should try it.